# Insert into SQL table or update record if exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, upsert

I want to add a row to a database table, but if a row exists with the same unique key, I want to update the row.

Here is my query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('$audit_no','$form_details_subquestion_id','$form_details_section_id','$mark') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mark = VALUES($mark)";
```

But, it will keep on inserting new record. Let's say `audit_section_id, form_details_subquestion_id, form_details_section_id` is unique key. If `audit_section_id, form_details_subquestion_id, form_details_section_id` exists it will not insert new record into the database; while update the record.

I also tried this:

```
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_‌​details_section_id`,`mark`)
VALUES ('$audit_no','$form_details_subquestion_id','$form_details_section_id','$mark')
```

I not sure is that the for loop problem of my code.

```
    for ($i=0; $i < ($_POST['count']); $i++)
{
    $form_details_subquestion_id    = $_POST['form_details_subquestion_id'][$i];
    $form_details_section_id        = $_POST['form_details_section_id'][$i];
    $mark                           = $_POST['mark'][$i];
    $remark                         = $_POST['remark'][$i]; 


    //$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `name`, `email`) VALUES (' ".$_POST['id']." ', ' ".$_POST['name']." ', ' ".$_POST['email']." ')";    

    $query = "REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`)
    VALUES ('$audit_no','$form_details_subquestion_id','$form_details_section_id','$mark')";
    $result = $db->query($query);
}
```

I'm using for loop to insert all the data.

Here is the output for echo $query;

```
  REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','89','1','1.00')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','86','1','1.00')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','87','1','1.00')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','88','1','1.00')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','85','1','1.00')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','83','1','1.00')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','84','1','1.00')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','81','1','1.00')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','82','1','1.00')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','98','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','99','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','100','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','101','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','102','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','96','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','97','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','90','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','91','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','92','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','93','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','94','1','2')
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','95','1','2')
```

SQL table

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `audit_section_markrecord` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `audit_section_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `form_details_subquestion_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `form_details_section_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mark` decimal(5,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dateofmodify` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Try using an `UPDATE` instead?

Comment: Use the REPLACE INTO command (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen bro, previously I am using UPDATE statement, but I not sure how to do insert new record using if else and checking in database.

Comment: @jeff bro, I not so sure the concept about REPLACE INTO.

Comment: So are you looking for PHP code, MySQL code, or both?  By the way, don't bro me if you don't know me :-/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen both :) bro is just a greeting :)

Comment: As the doc state "REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted."

Comment: @jeff ok thanks bro. Let me try out :D

Comment: @JEFF bro, I just tired REPLACE into.. It still continue to insert new record rather than update my record.

Comment: @Andrew: Can you include the `REPLACE INTO` query you tried?

Comment: @NathanTuggy "REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) 
           VALUES ('$audit_no','$form_details_subquestion_id','$form_details_section_id','$mark')"

Comment: @Andrew: Hopefully I got the query in there correct, but comments are not the place for non-trivial code. There's an [edit] button for a reason: use it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy yes ok. Thank you for your kind remind.

Comment: please, add an echo $query; inside the loop and edit with the output and edit with your table sql too.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer bro, I didnt get your mean.

Comment: in the line where you have this $query = "REPLACE INTO audit_ ..."; put this $query = "REPLACE INTO audit_"; echo $query . "<br>"; and edit your question with the output that you see when you run your page and edit too with the sql of your database table audit_section_markrecord

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer bro, just update the output :_

Comment: great, and now I need see the sql of your table, the create table ... of your  audit_section_markrecord, please edit your question with this info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92333/discussion-between-andrew-and-adrian-cid-almaguer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit after your last question edit:**

you have in your table this:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
....
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Your `id` (PRIMARY KEY) is autoincremental and your question is:

> I want to add a row to a database table, but if a row exists with the
>   same unique key, I want to update the row.

With your querys your never will have the same `id` because you never set the `id` value in your query, your query is:

```
REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`) VALUES ('602633','95','1','2')
```

and if you don't set the id value in your query the database system autoincrement automatically the `id`  column value, and you never will have to update a row.

---

This should be your query:

```
$query = "REPLACE INTO audit_section_markrecord(`audit_section_id`,`form_details_subquestion_id`,`form_details_section_id`,`mark`)
    VALUES ('$audit_no','$form_details_subquestion_id','$form_details_section_id','$mark')";
```

But the `audit_section_id`, `form_details_subquestion_id` and  `form_details_section_id` column values must match those of an existing row for the row to be replaced; otherwise, a row is inserted.

You can read more at:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

***EXAMPLE:***

Consider the table created by the following CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

When you create this table and run the statements shown in the mysql client, the result is as follows:

```
mysql> REPLACE INTO test VALUES (1, 'Old', '2014-08-20 18:47:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> REPLACE INTO test VALUES (1, 'New', '2014-08-20 18:47:42');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test; 
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | data | ts                  |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 | New  | 2014-08-20 18:47:42 |
+----+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now if you create a second table almost identical to the first, except that the primary key now covers 2 columns, as shown here (`PRIMARY KEY (id, ts)`):

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, ts)
);
```

When you run on test2 the same two REPLACE statements as we did on the original(first) test table, we obtain a different result:

```
mysql> REPLACE INTO test2 VALUES (1, 'Old', '2014-08-20 18:47:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> REPLACE INTO test2 VALUES (1, 'New', '2014-08-20 18:47:42');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM test2;
+----+------+---------------------+
| id | data | ts                  |
+----+------+---------------------+
|  1 | Old  | 2014-08-20 18:47:00 |
|  1 | New  | 2014-08-20 18:47:42 |
+----+------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is due to the fact that, when run on test2, both the id and ts column values must match those of an existing row for the row to be replaced; otherwise, a row is inserted.